# CSV - Add quotes around missing fields

Tags: linux, awk, sed, csv

My CSV file looks like this -

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
"AK","87","86","81","83","78",,
```

How do I transform it like this -

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
"AK","87","86","81","83","78","",""
```

Comment: Why two `,"",""`? Shouldn't it be: `"AK","87","86","81","83","78",""`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk note the two commas as the end. CSV delimits fields with a comma, so each comma should be surrounded by fields, so there is a field after the second comma, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple `sed` command will do:

```
sed -e 's/^,/"",/' -e 's/,$/,""/' -e 's/,,/,"",/g' file
```

Ouput (if there's a leading comma):

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
"","AK","87","86","81","83","78","",""
```

The first expression deals with a bare comma at the beginning of the line; the second expression deals with a bare comma at the end of the line; the third expression deals with misssing fields in the middle.